# FIRApp Linker Error ["_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp"]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, linker-errors

I have scoured SO and Google but can't find an answer that works. I have used the new Firebase Cocoapod on multiple projects but now, when adding it to a different project I am getting the following error.

[image]

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 with cocoapods 1.0.1.

Here is my podfile:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build directory (hold down option when selecting Product > Clean)? If this project was using older cocoapods as well, it might be worth doing `pod deintegrate` then `pod update` as well.

Comment: @IanBarber I tried `pod deintegrate` and cleaning the project with no luck. In the end I got the project to build by downloading the SDK and manually adding the frameworks to the project. I'm just curious if you know why this works instead of cocoapods? It's a relatively old project that has been on the App Store for over a year. Maybe there is something deep down in the build settings doesn't play well with the new cocoapods? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue? Stuck on this...

Comment: I don't remember exactly, off the time of my head I think I had to just repull it from the repo and take the losses. Try to save whatever you have done and try to integrate it with a clean version from the repo and then add Firebase.

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue?For me to same problem please help me if you solved this?

Answer (score 21):

Go to `Build Settings` > `Other Linker Flags` > on a new line `$(inherited)`.

Do a `Cmd+Ctrl+K` for a clean, and then build.

Comment: i didnt get it. what new line? what about debug, release sub items. can you add screenshot  just to be clear? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore (Xcode beta 9.3), and CocoaPods puts $(inherited) in by default. Still trying to figure out a solution for 2018

Comment: @Max not working for me either, adding manually frameworks to the projects solved my problem

Comment: I got it to work by changing the dependency from `Firebase/Messaging` to `FirebaseMessaging`

Comment: @Max Which "dependency"?  Won't work for me either.  But what did you do specifically?

Comment: Worked for me this morning in Xcode 10.1.  CocoaPids didn't put $(inherited) in by default in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks inhibit_all_warnings! use_frameworks!

## Pods for FCM

pod 'Firebase' pod 'Firebase/Core' pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end