# Firebase intergration error in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have intergrated firebase push notification in my app. I had installed cocoapods fine and do all the code in appdelegate.m file for firebase messaging. Also created certificate and uploaded to firebase to my project, i have followed all the procedure correctly but when i run the app i got some errors and app do not run and shows error while linking. My code for firebase is this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        [FIRApp configure];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshCallBack:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

        UIUserNotificationType type=(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings=[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:type categories:nil];

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
        return YES;
    }

    -(void)tokenRefreshCallBack:(NSNotification *)notification{
        NSString *refreshToken=[[FIRInstanceID instanceID]token];
        NSLog(@"Instance IDToken : %@",refreshToken);
        [self connecttoFirebase];
    }

    -(void)connecttoFirebase{
        [[FIRMessaging messaging]connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error){
            if (error !=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM %@",error);
            }else{
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM");
            }
            }];
    }

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
        NSLog(@"Message ID : %@",userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTgiI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/budaj.png)

Comment: what is the minium ios version you are supporting for your app ?

Comment: 10.0 version for my app. @AbdulKarim

Comment: May we see your podfile? Have you tried reinstalling your Firebase pod by commenting out your Firebase, pod install, then uncomment the pod and pod install again?

Comment: I have added screen shot check that. @Glenn

Comment: check if it is okay or not. @Glenn

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: i have added screenshot check that. @Himanth

Answer (score 0):

Sir David East's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38226058/3231194) :

Go to `Build Settings` > `Other Linker Flags` > on a new line `$(inherited)`.

Do a `Cmd+Ctrl+K` for a clean, and then build.

---

I also want to add these steps, rather than `Cmd+Ctrl+K`, it should be:

1. `Cmd+Shift+K`. Then:
2. `Cmd+AltOption+Shift+K`
3. Finally, build it.

Comment: Bro i have done that procedure, when i do this than i got one error of unknown argument swift. @Glenn

Comment: bro i have added screenshot after doing above procedure check in my question. @Glenn

Comment: remove -swift in Build Settings > Other Linker Flags

Comment: When i remove that it shows me 5 errors messages as in my screenshots in question. @priyadharshini

Comment: @Raheel Have you tried updating your `Cocoapod` and then update your Xcode's pod?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods then after that, execute `pod update` to update your Firebase pods.